# Undefined height

Tags: javascript, height, undefined

I have two divisions (menu and content). content's height is undefined so that it can expand. I wanted the menu to have the height of the "expanded" content.

I actually understood how to do it with offset.Height, but the height is undefined.

Is there any way I could find the height of the expanded division?

Comment: Why not you go for jQuery. $('#div').height() will give you the current height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do

```
$('#content').height(); //Assuming div content have id="content"
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice method for getting the height of an element, with examples here:
http://api.jquery.com/height/